# linearity of the expected value for discrete random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, self-learning

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants, and $g$ and $h$ are functions such that $g(X)$ and $h(X)$ are random variables.

I want to prove this with discrete variables.
$$E(\alpha g(X)+\beta h(X))=\alpha E(g(X))+\beta E(h(X))$$

So I don't know if this is right:
$$\alpha E(g(X))+\beta E(h(X))= \alpha \sum_i g(x_i)P(X=x_i)+\beta \sum_i h(x_i)P(X=x_i)$$
$$=\sum_i\alpha g(x_i)P(X=x_i)+\sum_i \beta h(x_i)P(X=x_i)$$
$$=\sum_i (\alpha g(x_i)+\beta h(x_i))P(X=x_i)$$
$$=E(\alpha g(X)+\beta h(X))$$

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: That is exactly it.  Is there any particular step you doubt?